# Unable to retrieve resource in custom maven plugin during compile phase

Tags: java, maven, resources, classpath, maven-plugin

I have created a custom maven plugin which runs in compile phase. The plugin attempts to find a resource on the class path, but can not find
it. 
The plugin:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>com.mygroup</groupId>
    <artifactId>myplugin-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <phase>compile</phase>
                <goals>
                    <goal>build</goal>
                </goals>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

In the plugin's code I am using:

```
InputStream is = this.getClass().getClassLoader().getResource("myFile.txt").openStream();
```

Which results in a NullPointerException when executing mvn clean
install, having tried to put myFile.txt in the project's root, src
folder or src/main/resources folder. Every time getResource returns
null.  I also tried using:

```
InputStream is = Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader().getResource("myFile.txt").openStream();
```

And also both with getResourceAsStream but nothing helps.

Does this have something to do with the compile phase? I would like to
have the plugin generate code based on properties in the input file.

Thanks!

Comment: You are mistaken things here. If you plugin will try to access a resource via getResource()...it will search within it's own jar or more accurate on the plugin classpath but **not** on the classpath of the project being built. Take a look into source code the maven-resources-plugin how to access the path of the project...

Comment: Thanks, but I am using the plugin in the project being built so it is looking in the correct class path. But I found the problem, I should not have specified the compile phase in execution. I will therefore answer my own question.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution. First I thought the problem went away when not specifying the phase, but when not doing that, it will not execute the plugin at all. 
What did the trick for me is simply use FileInputStream("myFile.txt") having myFile.txt in the project root.